# Inserting combo box values to database?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, combobox, binding

i use code from "wilko" now. but in the end i want to save i got error.

`Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Try
        dict.Add("Index 1", 1)
        dict.Add("Index 2", 2)
        dict.Add("Index 3", 3)
        dict.Add("Index 4", 4)
        cmbIndex.DataSource = New BindingSource(dict, Nothing)
        cmbIndex.DisplayMember = "Key"
        cmbIndex.ValueMember = "Value"
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try



        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblMasterAksesJalanSKRD (kode_perus, nm_perusahaan, nm_pimpinan, alamat, volume, lokasi, masa_berlaku, tgl_exp, index, foto) VALUES (@a0,@a1,@a2,@a3,@a4,@a5,@a6,@a7,@a8,@a9)"
            .Parameters.Add("@a0", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtkode.Text
            .Parameters.Add("@a1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtnmperus.Text
            .Parameters.Add("@a2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtnmpim.Text
            .Parameters.Add("@a3", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtalamat.Text
            .Parameters.Add("@a4", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtvol.Text
            .Parameters.Add("@a5", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtlok.Text
            .Parameters.Add("@a6", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtmasber.Text
            .Parameters.Add("@a7", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = Date.Now
            .Parameters.Add("@a8", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbIndex.SelectedValue ***(i still got error on this "Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.")***
            .Parameters.Add("@a9", OleDbType.Binary).Value = IIf(pb1.Image IsNot Nothing, arrimage, DBNull.Value)`

thank you very much

Greetings From Indonesia.

Answer (score 0):

Your binding will not work like that. Try using a dictionary and creating a new binding source:

```
    Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    dict.Add("Kota", 6000)
    dict.Add("Kabupaten", 5000)
    cmbIndex.DataSource = New BindingSource(dict, Nothing)
    cmbIndex.DisplayMember = "Key"
    cmbIndex.ValueMember = "Value"
```

The following now should work:

```
    .Parameters.add("@a8", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbIndex.SelectedValue
```

Comment: can help me please, i still got error on my program... really thanks.